# ASP.NET Core 2: In `Startup()`, how do I specify additional arguments to choose the right configuration?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

We are building a new ASP.NET Core app to deploy to a few different environments that require different Configuration options.  For example, `Azure`, `AWS`, and `local` for development.  Each needs different configuration settings.  We already use the common:

`.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)`

which handles debug vs staging vs prod, but we have a second dimension to it, so we also want a:

`.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{DeploySite}.json", optional: true)`

or something like that.  We could pass in the `DeploySite` on commandline or environment variable or whatever is convenient, but nothing like that seems exposed in the `IHostingEnvironment` offered in the `Startup` method.

How is this best accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 2+ this is done in `Program.CreateWebHostBuilder` instead of `Startup`. We do something almost identical in our deployments, requiring an `appsettings.<name>.json` file for configurations. We do it by passing in a command line parameter in the form of `--App:InstanceName <name>`. Then set it on launch:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWebHost host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

    host.Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
        {
            IConfigurationRoot commandConfig = config.Build();
            config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{commandConfig["App:InstanceName"]}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        });
}
```